# Perl regex matching: Match string with single word only, how to use negative lookbehind lookahead as well

Tags: regex, string, perl, sas

I'm genuinely exhausted in trying to get this regex to work. I'm using perl regex in sas. If anyone could help me I'd greatly appreciate it. I have three questions, consider the following lines of text (the line numbers are only there for reference):

```
1 weight
2 weightchange
3 weight change
4 weight percentile
5 change weight
6 percentile weight
7 **** weight pre op
8 water weight
9 weight percentile
10 myocardial infarction
```

1. How would I use regex to match `1` but NOT `2-9`? (is the a way to match a word that is at the beginning and end simultaneously?)
2. How would I use regex and negative lookahead / lookbehind assertions to match `1` and then explicitly exclude `2-6`?
3. How would I modify the regex suitable to solve Q2 to then exclude `7` and `8`?

Bonus question: How long did it take you to get *good* at using regex?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just use `^weight$` for Q1?

Comment: Your (1), as shown, is simple (`/^weight\s*$/`) ... and then the problem with that is that (2) and (3) aren't relevant -- you don't need all that to distinguish them.  If you really want it, as an exercise, it's a basic use of lookarounds. For example, `/weight(?!\s*(?:change|percentile))/` to have it match `weight` without listed words after it, etc. // It takes experience, so some years.  However, you can pick up basics pretty rapidly, for very adequate use. // Most importantly: please make your questions far more specific -- tell us _what_ is bothering, show us what you did.

Comment: By this question it appears that you may need a _thorough_ read on this, beginning to end, from some introductory text.  The [`perlretut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html) is good, and the part on [`lookarounds`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) in particular, I think. There are many other sources out there.  Better yet, perhaps a chapter from your favorite Perl book.  If you are trying to 'figure it out' by poklng around it may be tough. I'd say, first read up on it then play.

Comment: Correction for the first example in the comment above -- since your strings may have space at the beginning you need `/^\s*weight\s*$/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) @Barmar mentioned it already: `^weight$` is fine for doing what you're asking. Are you sure that's what you want though, i.e. "weight" on a line by itself?

2) You could do something like `/(?<!percentile )(?<!change )weight(?! ?change| percentile)/`. The negative lookbehinds can't be written as `(?<!change |percentile )` as the RE engine does not support variable width lookbehind but as the matches are zero-width you can just list them separately. All that looks awfully specific though. It would fail e.g. if your text contained these words separated by a line break.

3) Just add another negative lookbehind for `****` and `water`.

I'm not all that good at regex :) And I never sat down and decided to learn the ins and outs, that's pretty useless if you don't have a use case; you'll just forget it in a short while. Now that I've been using regexen for over 20 years I'm still learning new things, like how to match Unicode properties just a few weeks ago.

Comment: Technically, `^weight\z` for #1 as `^weight$` matches both `"weight"` and `"weight\n"`

Comment: Thanks so much. Sorry I didn't include more of what I have tried.

^weight$ was not successful however, to my surprise (as is often the case with regex code) that didn't match anything in the list..

I was trying to modify the code: /(?<!percentile )(?<!change )weight(?! ?change| percentile)/  instead to positive lookbehind/aheads, I tried this: /(?<=percentile )(?<=change )weight(?= ?change| percentile)/

But that actually doesn't match anything. Do you know why that is? :)

Comment: That change means you're asking for "weight" to be simultaneously preceded by "percentile" and "change", which doesn't make sense as only one of those can actually be there. So that will never match anything at all. The lookahead alone would work as it contains an alternation, so either of `change` with or without a preceding space, or `percentile` would be allowed.